# Replace URL in PHP code using HTTP Class

Tags: php

I want to replace http://www.wpfetish.com/ip2nation.php/?ip= with
http://ipinfo.io/yourip_here/country

in this code to get country code

```
/*Uses WordPress HTTP Class*/
if( !class_exists( 'WP_Http' ) )
    include_once( ABSPATH . WPINC. '/class-http.php' );

$request = new WP_Http;
/*
 * get country info based on the ip of user
 * requests to the plugin server for ip to country code
 */
    $result = $request->request( "http://www.wpfetish.com/ip2nation.php/?ip=$user_ip" );     

if(!empty($result['body'])){
    $res = json_decode($result['body']);
    if($res->status == 'success'){
        return strtoupper( $res->iso_code_2 );
    }
}

return 'default';

}
```

Comment: exactly how do you mean *"replace"*? you mean dynamically via the browser?

Comment: no just want to this http://www.wpfetish.com/ip2nation.php/?ip=$user_ip  to be  http://ipinfo.io/$user_ip/country  do i need to change any thing else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to change a few other things, because http://ipinfo.io doesn't return a body or status field:

```
$ curl ipinfo.io/8.8.8.8
{
  "ip": "8.8.8.8",
  "hostname": "google-public-dns-a.google.com",
  "city": "Mountain View",
  "region": "California",
  "country": "US",
  "loc": "37.3860,-122.0838",
  "org": "AS15169 Google Inc.",
  "postal": "94040"
}
```

And if you request just `/country` it doesn't return a JSON object:

```
$ curl ipinfo.io/8.8.8.8/country
US
```

So the full code you need is just this:

```
$request = new WP_Http;
$result = $request->request("http://ipinfo.io/$user_ip/country");     
return trim($result);
```

If you don't want to use WP_Http and want to check for some specific countries, here's the full code:

```
$user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$res = file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/${user_ip}/country");
$country = trim($res);
if(in_array($country, array("GB", "US"))) {
    // User is in the UK or US
}
```

Comment: Yeah, just don't forget to trim() the $res

Comment: thank you vey much for your time i tried this code but it deosn't work so i want to leave this plugin and i need to use code like this
 <?php
            
            $user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    
                $res = file_get_contents( "http://ipinfo.io/$user_ip/country" );     

    if ($res="UK || US") {
    echo "Have a good night!";
    
    } else {
    echo "Stoop!";
    } 

    ?>

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the URL value in the code, be careful not to lose the quotation marks, and test it.  You should be fine.